# Youtube HTML5 iframe embed has outline in IE on play

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, youtube, embed

I have a Youtube HTML iframe embed in my page, this is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gI2eO_mNM88?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;color=white&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;hd=1" width="470" height="264" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitAllowFullScreen></iframe>
```

If I press play I get an dotted 1px outline in IE9+8. I have this in my CSS:

```
embed,
object {
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

But that doesn't seem to help. It doesn't get an outline in Chrome or FF (both latest versions). I also tried putting the iframe in a div with the same dimensions as the iframe and giving that div overflow: hidden, but no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle for this case: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/UmTZy/

As you can see, outline appears inside `iframe` element. You cannot affect styling of elements inside `iframe` since it is beyond scope of your web page.

A rather ugly solution is to place `iframe` the way it hides 1px of it's outline. I've placed it inside slightly smaller div and positioned it so it hides this outline. If this solution is OK for you, you can see it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raQEH/

Comment: Not a very clean solution, but the best one so far anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe an id="iframe" and try this :

```
#iframe:active, #iframe:focus {
   border: none;
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `border:0;` if outline didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this problem at the youtube dev forum. Hope they can solve this from their site

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/gqt_G5d8HYM%5B1-25%5D